# Why SQL-Standard doesn't allow COUNT(col1, col2, ..., colN)

Tags: sql

The thing is simple, why doesn't SQL-Standard allow `COUNT(col1, col2, ..., colN)`? What's the reason behind?

It's pretty strange because, viceversa, SQL-standard allows `COUNT(DISTINCT col1, col2, ..., colN)`.

Comment: expr stands for expression.

Comment: @welcome . . . I don't even see that the `ALL` keyword is permitted in `COUNT()`.  Perhaps you just want `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: @jarlh my fault, I didn't mean what it stands for as abbreviation, but as nonterminal symbol.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want?  Simply `COUNT(*)` gives you the 'desired' answer.

- `COUNT(*)` is *usually* the thing to use.  It counts the number of rows (after filtering by `WHERE` and subject to `GROUP BY`).
- `COUNT(col)` is common, but often not necessary -- it counts rows with `col IS NOT NULL`.
- `COUNT(DISTINCT col)` determines how many different values there are for `col`.
- `COUNT(DISTINCT col1, col2)` determines how many different values there are for the combination of col1 and col2.

If you want to know why MySQL/MariaDB chose to leave out that syntax, you may have to ask the people who developed the SQL standard.

Comment: Yes, you got the problem: why did people who developed the SQL standard leave out this syntax?

Comment: `What do you want?Simply COUNT(*) gives you the 'desired' answer.`  -> COUNT(col1, col2) counts only if all columns are not null. So no, they are not the same.

Answer (score -1):

COUNT(NAME), COUNT(SURNAME) gets you ALL names and surnames. ALL is illegal in that context.

Comment: `COUNT(NAME, SURNAME)` itself is illegal. There is no such syntax present.

Comment: your right, wasn't paying enough attention, modifying post accordingly. Sorry